# Apache Lucene one-to-many query

Tags: java, lucene

I am trying to build a lucene query that will work with the following one-to-many relationship. I’m trying to-do this in lucene 5.5 but if i can’t then i’ll move towards upgrading the project to a newer version if necessary.

Say i have two objects like so. One Company that has multiple Items.

**Company (one)**

```
String name  
String address_state  
String address_street  
...  
Items items
```

**Items (many)**

```
Int item_id  
String item_name  
...  
Int item_price
```

How would i do a search for Companies in a particular state that have a particular item name with a price below a certain point? For instance, search for companies that are in CA with an item named “Phone” that also have a price below 150?

I only have around 300k companies but have around 5 million items. So id rather first filter by company if possible.

To anyone out there, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to look at block join approach in Lucene (and you could already use it in 5.5 version).

Example of the code, which should give an idea how to do this:

```
final Document item1 = new Document();
item1.add(new TextField("item_name", "item1", Field.Store.YES));
item1.add(new TextField("type", "item", Field.Store.YES));


final Document item2 = new Document();
item2.add(new TextField("item_name", "item2", Field.Store.YES));
item2.add(new TextField("type", "item", Field.Store.YES));

final Document company1 = new Document();
company1.add(new TextField("name", "company1", Field.Store.YES));
company1.add(new TextField("type", "company", Field.Store.YES));

writer.addDocuments(Arrays.asList(new Document[] {item1, item2, company1}));
```

In this example, I have 2 items created and attached to company. Mind the order of documents in `addDocuments` method - child documents (items in your case) should go before parent one (company in your case). You may have as many items as you want in this block.

Later, you could do very efficient querying using several types of queries from this [package](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_5_0/join/org/apache/lucene/search/join/package-summary.html).

Example of the query could be something like this:

```
BooleanQuery.Builder builder = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
    builder.add(new BooleanClause(new TermQuery(new Term("item_name", "item1")), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST));
    BooleanQuery childQuery = builder.build();
    ToParentBlockJoinQuery parentQuery =
        new ToParentBlockJoinQuery(
            childQuery,
            new QueryBitSetProducer(new TermQuery(new Term("type", "company"))),
            ScoreMode.Avg);
```

This query searched for all companies, which have items with name item1. You should be able to extend this pretty easy as well